# Dynamically change the Order total label

Tags: magento2, magentomodule

I'm working on a **Rental Module** for a Magento 2 website.
the products on the site can be rented for a week or month and I want to show this in the order total label
e.g order Total(per week) or order total(per month)

[image]

But I'm not sure how to change the label and which files I have to change. I found some articles but they did not work for me.

Comment: can you specify what you have try and what not working?

Comment: so far I have tried to override the shipping.php file

Answer (score 0):

You can change the label of the order total by using the Language CSV translation. Please follow the steps below:

1. Create /path/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n
2. Create Language CSV file in specified folder. Like en_US.csv
3. Add the label as per the website like below

Original,Translated

Order Total,Total (Per week)